# SOAP requests using Scala script

Tags: scala, soap

I'm looking to make a soap call in order to setup information for a series of tests.

In order to do this, I want to call an established soap request. I'm using gatling for the tests, so I'd like to do the data setup with scala/gatling as well. Is this something that can be easily done, and can one of you FINE PEOPLE show me an example of how?

Comment: There are Scala SOAP clients but first you better try Java SOAP clients. Have you tried any? You can generate the client code from wsdl.

Comment: I've not.  I already have the structural setup for Scala, so I'd rather use a Scala client if possible. That said, I don't know what you mean by generating client code from wsdl. Can you tell me more?

Comment: [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) is the description language SOAP API providers use to expose their API. If you have a copy of their WSDL (or if it's available at let's say example.com/myapi.wsd) then you can generate the client code. Making SOAP calls without relying on an auto-generated client is really tedious. Look at libraries like [Apache AXIS 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/).